# The Default Link Bandwidth in Mininet

Tags: hyperlink, default, bandwidth, mininet

When running `Mininet`, it is possible to create a new link and to also set the bandwidth (using `bw`). For example: `addLink(host, switch, bw=10, delay='5ms')`

To my understanding, it is also possible to create the link without specifically setting the bandwidth. My question to you is, **what is the default link bandwidth that is set if it is not given in the command?**

If there is not a default, is it just set to whatever the computer can best handle? If this is the case, I would assume that it would very depending on the computer that is currently running `Mininet`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this link](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/mininet-discuss/2015-January/005665.html), the default bandwidth does not have a specific value, seems unlimited, but is actually limited by the power of your system.

Also from [this link](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Introduction-to-Mininet) we have that :

> For CPU-limited experiments, you will also need to make sure that you carefully limit the CPU bandwidth of your Mininet hosts. If you mainly care about functional correctness, you can run Mininet without specific bandwidth limits

which again shows that the bandwidth is limited by the CPU.

Comment: Thank you, now that you point this out, it makes sense. A typical network's bandwidth is limited to the network's hardware; therefore, the weakest link in the network, typically. So, in the case of Mininet, because the network is virtual, the "network" would be that software in computer itself, and the weakest link in the virtual network would depend on the weakest piece of hardware in the computer.

Comment: @zim7563 exactly! Glad I helped, if you need anything else you can ask! I would also be glad if you could upvote my answer, given that it helped :)